# Whats the best way to support next versions of your SDKs/Frameworks in GitHub or Bitbucket?

Tags: ios, frameworks, sdk

I mean is it ok to have v1.0 as main branch and v2.0 as subbranch? And what if I'll create v3.0 SDK, subbranch of a branch v2.0?

OR

create new repo with "v2.0"/"v3.0" postfixes?

So the question is: what is the best way to support multiple different versions of your SDK and in the same time keep them in one place ?

Thx.

Comment: Or just overwrite v1.0 with v2.0 in a commit. That's how versioning works.

Comment: @H2CO3, I want user/programmer to have clear understanding that THIS is SDK v1.0 and THAT is SDK v2.0, so he can use whatever he needs.

Comment: Forunately enough, Git manages revision history (that's why we use it). One can check out a specific commit.

Comment: @H2CO3, So, I can just give a link to the latest v1.0 commit and be sure that this is SDK v1.0, and that is SDK v2.0?
Hmm... I dont quite like this solution, 'cause what if I need to fix some bug in SDK v1.0, but the latest version is 10.0 ? And again we are coming to branching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely create different repos per version. Assuming that those versions are different enough to be called 1.0, 2.0, 3.0. That will make life really easy for you in order to manage pull requests. Also better when it comes to branch generation.

IMHO, if you keep only one branch alive and overwrite versions, could be a mess in the end. Imagine that you have a new feature under development (v1.0) pending from an specific commit, whilst v2.0 has been improved and it os ready to be delivered. Sum up a pull request from a developer that has fixed loads of bugs in an early release of v1.0....

In this case, again IMHO, divide and conquer. Repo per version. Branches per status (feature branches, stable branches, release branches), and pull requests to handle external changes.

Hope you like it!

Comment: yep! thank you. Also thought that having multiple branches per version or one branch for all versions is not quite right. So, again, thank you!